# Can you create a VM Ware snapshot as part of a SCCM Task Sequence?

Tags: vmware-esxi, sccm-2012

What I would like to be able to do is create a deployment/task sequence in SCCM 2012 R2 that can be scheduled to run after hours, snapshot a VMWare VM then apply whatever patches I've deployed to it then, ideally, send me an email to let me know it is done so I can go check to make sure that all the services on that VM are still OK.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a PowerShell command at the start of your task sequence, then using [PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/) it's easy.

You'd use something like this to snapshot the VM.

```
New-Snapshot -VM VM -Name BeforePatch
```

There's a bunch of other options available for the `New-Snapshot` cmdlet, and you can read about them [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc/New-Snapshot.html).